# Let's stash the [stash] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

All questions that were tagged [stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stash) have been retagged to either [git-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stash), [atlassian-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-stash), [perl-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-stash), or [expressionengine-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expressionengine-stash).

**Please burn [stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stash), as it is too ambiguous.**

---

<del>The tag wiki for [stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stash) (182 questions tagged) starts like this:</del>

> <del>Use `git stash` when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory.</del>

<del>It's clearly about git-stash. But we also have a [git-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stash) (161 questions tagged). So they probably should be synonyms.</del>

<del>But there's more. Atlassian *also* has a Stash. And [stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stash) is used for questions about that as well. At least [33 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[stash]+atlassian) are about that. And of course, we have [atlassian-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-stash) for that.</del>

<del>**So what should we do?**</del>

- <del>I think the [142 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[stash]+git+is%3Aquestion+-[git-stash]) that are obviously about [git-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stash) should be retagged.</del>
- <del>Likewise, the questions about the Atlassian product should be retagged with [atlassian-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-stash).</del>
- <del>The tag wiki for [stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stash) should be edited to reflect this and should include a disambiguation pointing to [git-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stash) and [atlassian-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-stash).</del>
- <del>The [questions that are about neither](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+-%22git%22+[stash]+-[git]+-[atlassian]+-[jira]) should be examined and tagged appropriately.</del>

<del>But should we keep [stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stash) at all?</del>

---

<del>Aaaaaand there is yet another [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash). No idea how to tag those.</del>

---

<del>So I'm done with the easy retags.

Still left are 3 related to [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl), 4 related to [expressionengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expressionengine), and 1 related to [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino). I've no clue what to do with those. Perhaps someone else can take care of those?</del>

---

<del>Created a new tag [expressionengine-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expressionengine-stash). 4 to go.</del>

---

<del>Created a new tag [perl-stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-stash).</del>
<del>Created a new tag [ethercard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethercard) for the Arduino question.</del>

---

**All done. Let it burn.**

Comment: Let's retag the questions and let the tag die, if it _really_ has no other uses.

Comment: @JonasCz That's the thing, it seems to be [_something_ in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=232930) as well. But I don't think we want a [tag:stash-perl].

Comment: Obvious title: Stash the [stash] tag

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan maybe we need to generate a tag of meta-stash for meta conversations about stashing various stash tags? Or is that meta-stash-stash...

Comment: @TimOgilvy: My vote is for "Stash stash-[stash] stash", personally.

Comment: Now down to less than 50 questions tagged with [tag:stash]. All that could be retagged with [tag:git-stash] are done, I think. On to [tag:atlassian-stash].

Comment: How common is the use of "stash" in a drugs context in everyday Languste? Because "Seize [stash]" would be cool too

Comment: Err... that was supposed to mean "language." #$&"'ing autocorrect

Comment: These continual attempts at humour in titles when proposing tag burnination (which I suspect isn't even a real word) are starting to get tedious :-)